# Key location for stars

Tags: r

if I plot data with the stars() function and want to add a key, the key is clipped most of the times.
Of course, the key position can be adjusted via key.loc but its always a case to case adjustment. However, I fancy a somewhat automatic key location adjustment, as I'm trying to automate plotting of various data sets, with different numbers of columns and rows.

```
stars(pdata, scale=FALSE, draw.segments=TRUE, 
      key.loc=c(lx,ly), nrow = ceiling(numsep/2), ncol = ceiling(numsep/2))
```

And advise or hints or workaround would be welcome!

Thanks!
Johannes

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: Does changing the `key.xpd` argument help? Or making the labels smaller with `cex`?